# Form validation for textfield not working?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In javascript, I´m supposed to create a function that checks if a textfield within a form is empty. If it is and the user clicks submit, the user will not be allowed to proceed. I found what I considered a suitable solution to this on w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp). I´ve checked more times than I can remember and everything seems to be in order, but it´s not working!! Instead, when the submit button is clicked, the website calls a different function I have in javascript which it is not supposed to do...

**HTML code**

```
Other code
<p>
   <form method="post" name="form" action="" onsubmit="return validateName()">
   <label for="fullName">Namn: </label><input id="fullName" class="text" name="namn" type="text"> </input>
</p>
<p>
   <label for="epost">Epost: </label><input id="epost" class="text" name="epost" type="email"> </input>
</p>
<p>
   <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Skicka"> </input>
</p>
</form>
Other code
```

**Javascript code**

```
function validateName() {
   var a = document.forms["form"]["namn"].value;
   if (a == null || a == "") {
      alert("Name required");
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Clicking the submit button should call this function above (validateName), but instead it calls this function:

```
function alert() { 
   return confirm("Do you really wish to leave this website?");
}
```

I´ve looked through my code multiple times and can´t find anything that seems to be out of place. Can any of you find anything wrong? And maybe suggest a solution that solves my problem so my function will work properly?

I would be very grateful if someone could help me resolve this matter!

Comment: Try commenting out that alert function. Your console will error and you can figure out where it is being called from.

Comment: Also note that by calling the function "alert" you override the default alert function. Instead you should encapsulate your function definitions within a localized scope by using var alert = function(){};

Javascript by default declares functions in the global scope.

Comment: I see! Should have seen I accidentaly named my function the same as a default one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert` is a `predefined function` that you are using correctly once and incorrectly the second time. Simply change the name of YOUR `alert` function to something else, or just use `confirm` as it was `intended` and leave out the `function alert` part

**Correct:**

```
alert("Name required");
```

**Incorrect:**

```
function alert() { 
   return confirm("Do you really wish to leave this website?");
}
```

**one solution is to do this:**

```
function confirm_leaving(){
    return confirm("Do you really wish to leave this website?");
}
```

Comment: I understand now! Should have seen that, though I stared at it for so long I probably went blind. Thank you very much! Your explanation is easy to understand, especially with the code examples and "YOUR". Short yet consice.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are calling the `alert` function within your `validateName` function.

```
function validateName() {
   var a = document.forms["form"]["namn"].value;
   if (a == null || a == "") {
      alert("Name required");  //<- remove this
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, I wanted to call the alert function. Just not my own, but the default one. I now see the error was that I named my function the same as a predefined function, thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you may put this code instead of this : function validateName() { 
To correct this just put a this command : 
function validateName(this) {

Comment: The reason my code did not work was because I named one of my functions the same as a predefined one. That messed things up when I called the `alert()` function. But I solved it now.